# Python library to download directory

Tags: library, python, ssh, http

I write a small tool to compare two directories: [compare-with-remote](https://github.com/guettli/compare-with-remote)

One part of the tool is to recursively fetch directories.

The library should be able to fetch from these protocols:

- http https
- scp
- local

I could not find a library at pypi.

Before I reinvent the wheel I ask here.

I would like to support these syntax:

```
# local
compare-with-remote my-dir

# scp
compare-with-remote remote-host:my-dir

# scp
compare-with-remote user@remote-host:my-dir

# http
compare-with-remote https://host/my-dir
```

Required Features:

- open source (not GPL)
- Usable from python without subprocess